# Plotting of x y coordinates numbers on histogram in openCv with C++

Tags: c++, opencv

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzF0W.png)I am working on histogram calculation and plotting in opencv with C++. I am able to calculate and plot histogram on command window but I am unable to show the x and y coordinates on image. Can you suggest me about function for it? If you need any information, let me know.
thank you.

Comment: Why not use matplotlib? Err sorry I just realized this was for C++. I'm sure there's plotting libraries in C++, though. Or bindings for matplotlib.

Comment: I think you have to draw the axis yourself. I'm not aware of at least an OpenCV function doing that. 1. take min, max; 2. find rounded values in between for axis ticks; 3. draw axis and ticks; 4. draw labels beside axis ticks.

Comment: Thank you fro your comments.